# Compare common fields of 2 instances from different classes

Tags: java, class, compare, equals, equality

Is there in java a more easy way to compare common fields(*same name and type*) of instances of different class without explicitly checking each field against another.

```
moo.getFoo() == doo.getFoo();
moo.getRoo().equals(doo.getRoo())
```

-

```
Class Moo {
  private int foo;
  private Object roo;
}

Class Doo {
  private int foo;
  private Object roo;

  private String ho;
}
```

Or at least is it possible in that case

```
Class Doo extends Moo {    
  private String ho;
}
```

Comment: You mean you want to rely on the computer to magically know which fields you want to compare and which ones you don't?

Comment: @Stultuske at least those of same type and field name, yes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the [CompareToBuilder](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/builder/CompareToBuilder.html) or [EqualsBuilder](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/builder/EqualsBuilder.html) from [Apache Commons Lang](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/). This Utilities create automatically the result for the compareTo(), equals() or hashCode() methods for all fields of the class.

```
public int compareTo(Object o) {
     return CompareToBuilder.reflectionCompare(this, o);
}


public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    return EqualsBuilder.reflectionEquals(this, obj);
}
```